# Django CRM Need to invite agents by admins using email address

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an uncompleted django CRM. I have 2 types of users:

Agents: can post and view data.

Admins: can view and edit data.

The thing is i need each admin to invite the users to CRM.

i need it to work as following:

- Admins will have access to a form where they can write down the agents name and email, once theysubmit the form and an email will be sent to the agent.
- The agent will receive an email with another form to set their username and password so they can login

do you have any idea what i should look for or how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate an activation key each time Admin adds a new user. Include that key in the URL you send to the agent for activating their account. When the agent clicks on the URL with the activation key, verify the key. If verification is successful, allow them to set their username and password, other redirect them an error page.

you can try following to generate Activation Key

```
salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
usernamesalt = agentEmail
if isinstance(usernamesalt, unicode):
usernamesalt = usernamesalt.encode('utf8')
activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+usernamesalt).hexdigest()
```